# Disconnect previous client socket.io socket in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, websocket, socket.io

I am creating a game lobby with multiple game rooms using node.js and socket.io. What I am trying to do is prevent the user from opening the lobby in multiple tabs. My thoughts were that when a new tab is opened, to disconnect the previous one. I thought I could accomplish this by keeping track of the socket.id of the already open tab.

```
//Keep track of the online users
var onlineUsers = new Array();

sessionSockets.on('connection', function(err, socket, session){
    socket.on('joinlobby', function(){
        //Disconnect the users previous socket if their username is already in the onlineUser array
        console.log("DISCONNECTED: " + onlineUsers[session.username]);
        socket.disconnect(onlineUsers[session.username]);
        onlineUsers[session.username] = socket.id;
        console.log("CONNECTED: " + onlineUsers[session.username]);
    });
});
```

Joinlobby is triggered when the page is first loaded. I am using [session.socket.io](https://github.com/wcamarao/session.socket.io) so I can access session data within the socket. I am using the username as the array key, and storing the current socket.id. Now the problem I am having is that seems to behave a little inconsistently. Sometimes it does nothing and neither tab is disconnected, whereas other times it appears both tabs are disconnected. There are no errors in the console, so can anyone see a problem with my approach? An example of the console output is:

```
DISCONNECTED: dOW2y-fq-aDW7t0sRUKn
   info  - booting client
   info  - transport end by forced client disconnection
   info  - transport end (booted)
CONNECTED: 9vZbMC85x9OQsFo9RUKo
```

Even though it says connected, it won't let me send or receive any messages. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`socket.disconnect(onlineUsers[session.username]);`
You are actually disconnecting new socket rather than old.
If you have a pointer to old socket, call `.disconnect()` to it.

Something like:

```
var sockets = { };
sessionSockets.on('connection', function(err, socket, session){
    sockets[socket.id] = socket;

    socket.on('joinlobby', function(){
        //Disconnect the users previous socket if their username is already in the onlineUser array
        var onlineSocketID = onlineUsers[session.username];
        if (onlineSocketID && onlineSocketID !== socket.id) {
            console.log("DISCONNECTED: " + onlineUsers[session.username]);
            sockets[onlineSocketID].disconnect();
            delete sockets[onlineSocketID];
        }
        if (onlineSocketID !== socket.id) {
            onlineUsers[session.username] = socket.id;
            console.log("CONNECTED: " + onlineUsers[session.username]);
        }
    });
});
```

And as extra comment here - personally I would not identify users by their username, but would use internal user ID's for that purpose, but that depends on your application logic.

As well using that logic, if you send 'joinlobby' message twice from client, it will result in self disconnect, so I've added check as well.